# Custom component inside tab ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs, components

I created a custom component and it works on main page but not inside a tabPage. What is wrong on this code? Thanks guys.

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SuperTabsModule } from 'ionic2-super-tabs';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { NewsItemComponent } from '../components/news-item/news-item';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    NewsItemComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SuperTabsModule.forRoot(),
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

home.html:

```
<ion-header  no-border>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <button ion-button menuToggle icon-only>
      <ion-icon name='menu'></ion-icon>
    </button> 
    <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" ></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="openFavoritesPage()">
        <ion-icon name="heart-outline"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-tabs [ngClass]="{'visible': !showSearchList}" toolbarColor="light" toolbarBackground="primary" indicatorColor="danger" badgeColor="light">
    <ion-tab [root]="page1" [rootParams]="{'type': 'all'}" title="All"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="page2" [rootParams]="{'type': 'news'}" title="News"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="page3" [rootParams]="{'type': 'reviews'}" title="Reviews"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="page4" [rootParams]="{'type': 'videos'}" title="Videos"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="page5" [rootParams]="{'type': 'photos'}" title="Photos"></ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>

  <ion-list class="searchitens" [ngClass]="{'visible': showSearchList}">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{ item }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  page1: any = 'NewsPage';
  page2: any = 'NewsPage';
  page3: any = 'NewsPage';
  page4: any = 'NewsPage';
  page5: any = 'NewsPage';

  showSearchList: boolean = false;
  items: string[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.initializeItems();
  }

  getItems(ev: any) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items
    this.initializeItems();

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.showSearchList = true;
      this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
        return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }else{
      this.showSearchList = false;
    }
  }

  initializeItems() {
    this.items = [
      'Mercedes Benz',
      'Chrysler',
      'Dodge',
      'Jeep',
      'Ford',
      'Lincoln',
      'Tesla Motors',
      'GMC',
      'Chevrolet',
      'Cadillac'
    ];
  }

  openFavoritesPage(){
      this.navCtrl.push("FavoritesPage");
  }



}
```

news.html:

```
<ion-content padding>
        <news-item ></news-item>    
</ion-content>
```

news.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-news',
  templateUrl: 'news.html',
})
export class NewsPage {

  items: any = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log(this.navParams.data.type);
  }

}
```

news-item.html(component):

```
<div>
  {{text}}
</div>
```

news-item.ts(component):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'news-item',
  templateUrl: 'news-item.html'
})
export class NewsItemComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello NewsItemComponent Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World';
  }

}
```

Comment: did you try my answer ?

Comment: Bruno can you share some more details how did you solve this? I'm having same problem. Thank you.

Comment: Sure. First you have to create a component.module.ts class 
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicModule} from 'ionic-angular';
import {LabelGenerator} from "./labelgenerator/labelgenerator";
@NgModule({
    declarations: [LabelGenerator],
    imports: [IonicModule],
    exports: [LabelGenerator]
})
export class CustomComponentsModule {}
Import it on your module page on import section.
@NgModule({
    declarations: [Dashboard],
    imports: [
        CustomComponentsModule,
        IonicPageModule.forChild(Dashboard)
    ],
})
export class DashboardModule {}

Comment: Sorry I could not ident the code

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use a custom component inside a TabPage, this page cannot be a lazyload Module.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**
Create a module for your custom component and add your component class into the module declarations and exports.

Then in your news.module.ts imports, import your custom component. This is how I'm using custom components in my lazy loaded pages.

Comment: Can you provide some more information? because I'm having same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to prior versions, but in Ionic 5, it needs to be declared in `tabs.module.ts`, 
**not** `app.module.ts` (due to lazy loading as @Bruno Verçosa mentioned).