# Using a Custom Angular Component in Multiple Ionic Tabs

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, module

I created an Ionic app using the tabs starter project template. I created a custom component to use in these 3 tabs. But when I use the component in each tab `*.html` file, it says it isn't a known element.

I tried declaring the component in the `tabs.module.ts` file, as one of the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730990/custom-component-inside-tab-ionic-3) says to do, but it still says the same thing.

In the following 3 questions and their answers they are talking about importing the module that contains the component they need:

- [Using component from another module (Angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59168684/using-component-from-another-module-angular)
- [Angular - Using a component across multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305169/angular-using-a-component-across-multiple-modules)
- [can't use custom component in `app.component.ts` in ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47898616/cant-use-custom-component-in-app-component-ts-in-ionic-3)

My component is not in another module, do I need to make another module and declare the component in that, and then import that module into the 3 tab modules where I want to use the component? Or is there a way I can just import the component and use it?

I don't think it is needed for this question, but if you need, tell me to add my code.

**Read Before You Answer**

1. I know that I can create a module, declare my custom components, export them, and import that module in the tab modules to use the component.
   What I want to know is if there is a way to import just the component into the 3 modules to use that component in there.
2. Many answers on StackOverflow have said that you can just declare your component in the `tabs.module.ts` file, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export your Template in a Module to import it somewhere else, alternatively you could manually copy the Template in the Html, but that would be more Work and upkeep than just creating a component module like this:

You can make a component folder with all the individual component folders inside and add a component.module.ts in the upper component folder.

In the component.module.ts you only need to declare and export it like this:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CustomComp1Component } from './custom-comp1/custom-comp1.component';

import { CustomComponent } from './custom/custom.component';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [CustomComponent, CustomComp1Component],
    imports:  [
                CommonModule,
                IonicModule
              ],
    exports: [CustomComponent, CustomComp1Component]
})
export class ComponentModule {}
```

only thing left to do now is import the componentmodule in the .module.ts of the page you want to use a component in (in your case the 3 individual tab1/2/3.module.ts).

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule,
    ComponentModule // <- component Module
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage],
})
```

Now you should be able to use html elements with the @Component({}) selector as name in the pages you imported component module to.

I hope this solves your Problem.

PS: If I understood the Ionic Tab structure correctly importing and using the component in the tabs page would only allow you to use the component in the footer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I knew I could do this, but I was hoping there was a way to do it without creating a whole new module just to use one component (well, maybe 2 when my project is finished) in 3 tabs. Is this the only way to do it? If it is, I will use this method, but I really want to just use the component I made, without creating a module to import it to the 3 tab modules.

Comment: @JacobHornbeck Correct me if I understood you wrong but you want a Component without a Module? So just a Template? If you want that template to be defined only *once* in the application you need to export it from somewhere and import it where you want to use it the way to do it is a Module.

Comment: Is there a specific component thing in Angular for a template? I just want to use the one component I made and use it in each of the three tabs (which use modules)

Comment: You could use ngTemplate https://angular.io/api/core/ng-template but again I think is it less work to make a component module instead of putting the template in 3 different HTMLs.

Comment: So it seems that I cannot just import my one component into the 3 tab modules without declaring and exporting it from a module of it's own. Thank you. If you modify your answer to state that (that it can't be done (as far as we know) to just use a component in 3 tab modules, and that the easiest way is to have a component module), I will mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare it in the tabs.module.ts like so:

```
NgModule({
   imports: [ ],
   declarations: [MyComponent]
})
```

Comment: Please see my second paragraph to see why this answer doesn't help me. Unless there is more to add

Comment: I also just tried it in a completely new Ionic Tab project, and it doesn't work to just import it in the `tabs.module.ts` file. So either this doesn't work, or there is something missing from this (and many other answers)